# Возвратить переменную из AJAX-запроса в скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть Функция1, в которой я вызываю Функцию2, которая содержит AJAX-запрос.
Сам  AJAX-запрос возвращает значение, которое нужно передать в Функцию1.
Выглядит так:

```js
function function2(x,y, ...){
        $.ajax({
            url: "./block1Action.php",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                x:x,
                y:y,
                ...
            },
            success: function(res){
                res; //res - это число которое я должен вернуть в function1, как число 
            }
        });
    }
function function1(){
    var res = function2(10,20,...);
    alert(res); 
}
```

Comment: А кто вам мешает сделать `success: function(res){
                return res;            }`

Comment: Возвращает undefined и для res и для return 123;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо зарегистрировать функцию обратного вызова, что-то вроде этого:

```
function test() {
    myFunction(function(d) {
        //processing the data
        console.log(d);
    });
}

function myFunction(callback) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'data to send',
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Не подскажите, как тогда передать переменные в myFunction?

Comment: @РусланГохгалтер Если используете код то увидите. Они в переменной `d`. Там сделан `console.log` посмотрите значения